# Translating from Java: How to define lambda members for enum types in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, enums

In Java, it is possible to do the following for *e.g.* defining different variants of a simple calculation (in this case, inverted document frequency weights from the total number of documents D and the numbe rof documents that contain a term d):

```
package an.nlp.library.weights;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public enum IDF implements BiFunction<Long,Long,Double> {
    UNARY( ( D, d ) -> 1d ),
    IDF(   ( D, d ) -> Math.log(   D / d     ) ),
    IDFS(  ( D, d ) -> Math.log1p( D / d     ) ),
    PIDF(  ( D, d ) -> Math.log(   D - d / d ) ),
    ;

    private BiFunction<Long,Long,Double> func;

    private IDF( BiFunction<Long,Long,Double> func ) {
        this.func = func;
    }

    public Double weight( long D, long d ) {
        return func.apply( D, d );
    }

    @Override
    public Double apply( Long t, Long u ) {
        return func.apply( t, u );
    }
}
```

This can then be called from client code via, e.g.:

```
getIdf( long D, long d, IDF mode ) {
    return mode.apply( D, d );
}
```

etc.

How would one accomplish the same in C++? i.e something like, calling something like:

```
// Obviously wrong, as I have no idea how to do it, hence the qeustion:
std::vector<double> getIdfWeights( long D, std::vector<double> ds, IDF mode ) {
    return std::transform( ds.begin(), ds.end(), ds.begin(), IDF );
}
```

In other words, what would be the correct syntax to use to add 1) members to an enum type in C++ and 2) have those member values be lambdas that could then be called from somewhere else? From what I've been reading, apparently this is what enum classes are for, but I'm a C++ n00b so I don't entirelly understand how those work.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent in C++ am afraid. You can define an enum class with integer values from 0, and then use a lookup table of `std::function<int(int)>` to achieve something similar.

Comment: Can you sow a usage example? There is no real equivalence in c++, but if you just want a bunch of named function objects this should not be too big of a problem.

Comment: @MikeMB eeeh, the java I have is not too different from the initial version, and I don't have a C++ example, because I don't even know if this can be done... but I copied some real production code and my (certainly wrong) attempt at pseudo code. No idea is this helps, sorry.

Comment: I guess Caleth already gave you a correct answer then. Although this can be implemented much more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums in C++ are only integer values. They can't have members. `enum class` just removes integer conversions from the enum values.

You can do something similar with a class, e.g.

```
class Foo
{
    int(*)(int) func;
    int value;
public:
    operator int() {
        return value;
    };
    int operator()(int i) {
        return func(i);
    }
    static constexpr Foo Value_A = { frob, 0 };
    static constexpr Foo Value_B = { mung, 1 };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would be the syntax for calling Value_A in this case?

Comment: @gorgonzola `int asdf = Foo::Value_A(42);`

Comment: You don't need a std::function. A simple function pointer would do an be way more efficient.

Comment: Also I'd make Value_A and B const(expr)

Comment: Ok, I see that this javaism may be the wrong way in C++. @Caleth, could you add a minimal example of how to accomplish the same with function pointers? i.e. a set of functions that can be selected by passing a value from a fixed set of values?

Comment: A std::map<int, int(*)(int)> would do

Comment: @gorgonzola: Does this have to be an arbitrary set of values or can it be just all numbers from a certain interval?

Comment: @MikeMB, set range; as per the question example, I just need to be able to choose from a set of variations of a weighting function. but Caleth's suggestion of using a simple map seems to cut it. thanks!